# Why does std::iterator not define const_reference and const_pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

So, I made my own "standard compliant" container. I defined nested classes called `iterator` and `const_iterator` which derive from

```
std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, value_type>
```

where `value_type` is a typedef inside my new container class. I derive from `std::iterator` so that I can easily do

```
typedef typename std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,value_type>::value_type value_type;
typedef typename std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,value_type>::difference_type difference_type;
// ... etcetera
```

inside my nested iterator classes. However, cppreference.com says `std::iterator` does not have typedefs for a const_reference nor for a const_pointer. I can typedef them myself, but I am puzzled as to why these typedefs are omitted.

Comment: You can define them if you like, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just reviewed the spec.  `const_pointer` is only defined as part of the allocator types, `std::allocator`, `std::allocator_traits`, and container types, and has nothing whatsoever to do with iterators.  Therefore, it makes sense that `std::iterator` does not define a `const_pointer` typedef.

This makes sense when you think about it, because the constness of the value pointed at is inferred by the type of the iterator itself.  In the containers, `iterator` always refers to a mutable value, and `const_iterator` always refers to a `const` value, so neither has any need for a `const_pointer` typedef.

Since the concept of a `const_iterator` is slightly confusing, lets quickly review `const`.  The key thing to take away is that a `const iterator` and a `const_iterator` are *very* different things, and yes, there are `const const_iterator`s.

```
 a regular iterator models these two concepts
 int*; //changable pointer, to a changable int.  Modeled by iterator.
 int* const; //constant pointer, to a changable int.  Modeled by const iterator.
 //note that iterator doesn't ever refer to `const int`.

 a const_iterator models these two concepts
 const int*; //changable pointer to constant int. Modeled by const_iterator
 const int* const; //constant pointer to constnat int. Modeled by const const_iterator.
 //note that const_iterator ALWAYS refers to `const int`.
```

Comment: But what if some function has an argument with type `const iterator&` and needs to access the reference pointed to by the iterator? In that case, it would be nice if my iterator defined both the non-const and the const version of `operator*()`, and IN that case, as of now, I need to define my own version of const_reference to make that work. I suppose having a function that accepts a `const iterator&` is better off accepting a `const const_iterator&`.

Comment: @rwols An iterator is like a pointer. You are confusing the `const`ness of the iterator itself with the `const`ness of the object pointed to. `operator*()` is always `const`, so may be called on a `const` or non-`const` iterator. But the result is the same: `typename iterator::reference`. And the latter is `const` or not depending on how the iterator was obtained (e.g. from a `const` container or not).

Comment: @rwols: I've added a brief summary of how const works with iterators to try to clarify matters.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for the explanation, I'll model my iterators on this concept.